# Changing Bootstrap grid element padding depending on screen size

Tags: html, ruby, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

How can I have different padding depending on the screen size. 
For example I want col-sm-7 of media body to have `padding: 26px 16px 30px 10px;`
while col-md-8 of media body to have: `padding: 32px 30px 10px 35px;`

This is my that part of my code:

```
<div class="media-body  col-sm-7 col-md-8 ">
           <h4 class="media-heading"><%= link_to 'Contacts', root_path, class: 'media-heading' %></h4>
           <p class="hidden-sm">Where to find the <strong>Creatives</strong> contact module and more.</p>
</div>
```

This is my application.css.scss file:

```
.media-body .col-md-8 {
    padding: 32px 30px 10px 35px;
}

.media-body .col-sm-7 {
    padding: 26px 16px 30px 10px;
}
```

This css didn't work, is there a way to call the col classes in the Css file without it having affect other similar col classes int he rest of the document and get the desired padding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the space between .media-body .col-md-8 in the css.

so it reads as...

```
.media-body.col-md-8 {
    padding: 32px 30px 10px 35px;
}

.media-body.col-sm-7 {
    padding: 26px 16px 30px 10px;
}
```

Comment: I don't think this approach works. It will apply both paddings (overriding the first one) as both classes apply at the same time.